# How to subscribe to a topic on Cloud Pubsub with MQTT client

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I publish to a topic to pubsub. Multiple 3rd parties would like to subscribe to this topic. They have *nothing* to do with GCP and would like to use MQTT CLI to listen to messages. What are the steps to achieve this?